# Conditional Sum in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm not very good at SQL, so I've been trying to just handle this through PHP and doing very basic mySQL queries, but apparently I keep running out of memory (in PHP) since I'm handling a lot of data (and doing tons of horrible nested foreach's). I'm hoping there might be a way to re-write my SQL to make this not happen.

Here's the tables I'm dealing with (showing only relevant fields):

Organizations

- OrgID

FundingCycles

- CycleID
- NonUnityCutBackAmount
- UnityCutBackAmount

AdministrativeRequests

- CycleID
- OrgID
- AmountRequested
- AmountFunded
- PerOff

CapitalRequests

- CycleID
- OrgID
- AmountRequested
- AmountFunded
- PerOff

EventRequests

- CycleID
- OrgID
- AmountRequested
- AmountFunded
- PerOff
- UnityReq

So, here's the complicated part. I need to create sums for each organization of the `AmountRequested`, `AmountFunded`, (those two seem decently easy, although not sure about summing across multiple tables), and a calculated field `AmountAfterCutback` from requests that are in all request tables (`AdministrativeRequests`, `CapitalRequests`, `EventRequests`).

`AmountAfterCutback` is equal to: `AmountFunded - (AmountFunded * Cutback`).

That might be simple enough if the cutback was just one value. However, the `Cutback` comes from the `FundingCycles` table. So I can't just straight sum and apply the cutback, I have to find out the cutback for each request, and to do that I have to look at each request, and then by its `CycleID` check and see what the cutback for that request is in the `FundingCycles` table.

By default, `Cutback` would be equal to `NonUnityCutBack`. However, if the request is a `Unity` request (`EventRequests` only, `UnityReq == 1`), the cutback is equal to `UnityCutBack`. It gets even MORE challenging, however, in that a cutback can be applied individually to each request, overriding the unity or nonunity cutbacks (if `PerOff is > 0`).

So, somehow I have to sum every request an organization has made, and properly calculate the fields mentioned above. I'll show my solution below, which I'll warn is definitely not pretty, and at this point not even functional as it runs out of memory when trying to process it via PHP. I know there HAS to be a better way to do this. Some way to do a conditional calculation of each request so it can be summed in the query rather than my below clunky PHP solution? Any ideas? Thanks for anyone who's had the patience to even read this far, I know this is a PITA of a question. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function calculate_public_records()
{
      $total_req_total = 0;
      $total_funded_total = 0;
      $total_cutback_total = 0;

      $organizations = array();

      foreach($this->organizations as $org)
      {
          $id = $org['OrgID'];
          $org_req_total = 0;
          $org_funded_total = 0;
          $org_cutback_total = 0;

          $cycles = array();

          foreach($this->cycles as $cycle)
          {
                $cycle_req_total = 0;
                $cycle_funded_total = 0;
                $cycle_cutback_total = 0;

                $cycle_requests = array();

                foreach($this->request_types as $type)
                {
                    $reqs = $this->funding_request_model->getRequests($type, $cycle['CycleID'], $id);
                    foreach($reqs as $r)
                    {
                        $cutback = $cycle['NonUnityCutBack'];
                        if ($type == "Event") $cutback = ($r->UnityReq == 1) ? $cycle['UnityCutBack'] : $cutback;
                        $cutback = ($r->PerOff != 0) ? $r->PerOff : $cutback;

                        $request = array();
                        $request['id']        = $r->ReqID;
                        $request['type']      = $type;
                        $request['name']      = $r->Title;
                        $request['requested'] = number_format($r->RequestTotal, 2);
                        $request['funded']    = number_format($r->AmtFunded, 2);
                        $request['cutback']   = number_format(($r->AmtFunded - ($r->AmtFunded * $cutback)), 2);

                        $cycle_req_total += $request['requested'];
                        $cycle_funded_total += $request['funded'];
                        $cycle_cutback_total += $request['cutback'];

                        $cycle_requests[] = $request;
                    }

                }

                $cycle_totals = array();
                $cycle_totals['requested'] = number_format($cycle_req_total, 2);
                $cycle_totals['funded'] = number_format($cycle_funded_total, 2);
                $cycle_totals['cutback'] = number_format($cycle_cutback_total, 2);

                $org_req_total += $cycle_req_total;
                $org_funded_total += $cycle_funded_total;
                $org_cutback_total += $cycle_cutback_total;

                $cycles[] = array('name' => $cycle['CycleName'], 'requests' => $cycle_requests, 'totals' => $cycle_totals);
          }

          $org_totals = array();
          $org_totals['requested'] = number_format($org_req_total, 2);
          $org_totals['funded'] = number_format($org_funded_total, 2);
          $org_totals['cutback'] = number_format($org_cutback_total, 2);

          $total_req_total += $org_req_total;
          $total_funded_total += $org_funded_total;
          $total_cutback_total += $org_cutback_total;

          $organizations[] = array('id' => $org['OrgID'], 'name' => $org['Organization'], 'cycles' => $cycles, 'totals' => $org_totals);
      }

      $totals = array();
      $totals['requested'] = number_format($total_req_total, 2);
      $totals['funded'] = number_format($total_funded_total, 2);
      $totals['cutback'] = number_format($total_cutback_total, 2);

      return array('organizations' => $organizations, 'totals' => $totals);
```

**Calculation summary:**

```
# For tables AdministrativeRequests, CapitalRequests & EventRequests, calculate:

    SUM(AmountRequested)
    SUM(AmountFunded)

# For tables AdministrativeRequests, CapitalRequests & EventRequests, calculate:

    AmountAfterCutback = AmountFunded - (AmountFunded * Cutback)

# Cutback calculation pseudocode

if( <table>.PerOff > 0 ) {
    Cutback = <table>.PerOff
} elseif ( <table> == EventRequests && EventRequests.UnityReq == 1 ) {
    Cutback = FundingCycles.UnityCutBack
} else {
    Cutback = FundingCycles.NonUnityCutBack
}
```

Comment: How big of a dataset are we talking here?

Comment: You really should take the time to learn SQL. It's not hard - and you should never do what your database can do for you.

Comment: To clarify (pseudo), `AmountRequested, AmountFunded = SUM(*Requests.Amount*)`, `AmountAfterCutback = AmountFunded - (AmountFunded * IF(UnityReq, FundingCycles.UnityCutBackAmount, FundingCycles.NonUnityCutBackAmount)`. If, however, `PerOff` is non-zero, is that applied instead of any other cutback or with?

Comment: I've added a summary of the calculations that I think need to be carried out. This might save others from having to work it.  Please check and update as necessary.

Comment: Haven't got to look over all the answers yet, but I've updated the calulations pseudocode just slightly. It's not for table Organizations to get the SUM(AmountRequested) and SUM(AmountFunded), its for all Request tables (AdministrativeRequests, CapitalRequests, EventRequests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt - updated to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`:

```
SELECT OrgID,
       SUM(AmountRequested),
       SUM(AmountFunded),
       SUM(AmountFunded - (
           AmountFunded * 
           IF( PerOff > 0,
               PerOff,
               IF( UnityReq = 1,
                   UnityCutBackAmount,
                   NonUnityCutBackAmount
               )
           )
       )) AS AmountAfterCutback
  FROM (
SELECT o.OrgID,
       ar.AmountRequested,
       ar.AmountFunded,
       ar.PerOff,
       null AS UnityReq,
       fc_ar.CycleID,
       fc_ar.NonUnityCutBackAmount,
       fc_ar.UnityCutBackAmount
  FROM Organizations o
  JOIN AdministrativeRequests ar
    ON ar.OrgID = o.OrgID
  JOIN FundingCycles fc_ar
    ON fc_ar.CycleID = ar.CycleID
 UNION ALL
SELECT o.OrgID,
       cr.AmountRequested,
       cr.AmountFunded,
       cr.PerOff,
       null AS UnityReq,
       fc_cr.CycleID,
       fc_cr.NonUnityCutBackAmount,
       fc_cr.UnityCutBackAmount
  FROM Organizations o
  JOIN CapitalRequests cr
    ON cr.OrgID = o.OrgID
  JOIN FundingCycles fc_cr
    ON fc_cr.CycleID = cr.CycleID
 UNION ALL
SELECT o.OrgID,
       er.AmountRequested,
       er.AmountFunded,
       er.PerOff,
       er.UnityReq,
       fc_er.CycleID,
       fc_er.NonUnityCutBackAmount,
       fc_er.UnityCutBackAmount
  FROM Organizations o
  JOIN EventRequests er
    ON er.OrgID = o.OrgID
  JOIN FundingCycles fc_er
    ON fc_er.CycleID = er.CycleID
) tmp
 GROUP BY OrgID;
```

Comment: So, I thought this method worked perfectly, but I'm running into an interesting problem. It turns out, if there are two requests with the same AmountRequested, with the same CycleID, with the same OrgID, the query disregards one of them. Any idea on how to work around this?

Comment: @David Savage: Yes, sorry - change UNION to UNION ALL. UNION removes duplicate rows. I should have spotted that.

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it. Thanks for all your help, I've learned a lot of SQL along the way just figuring out the query you've wrote :)

Answer (score 2):

Learn SQL. A quick read suggests the answer might be something like...

```
    SELECT orgid
    , SUM(requested) AS amountrequested
    , SUM(funded) AS amountfunded
    , SUM(IF(unityreq=1, unitycutback, nonunitycutback) * funded) 
           AS amountaftercutback
    FROM
    ( 
      SELECT cycleid, orgid, unityreq, 
        SUM(amountrequested) as requested, SUM(amountfunded) as funded
      FROM
        (
           (
           SELECT cycleid, orgid, AmountRequested, AmountFunded, 0 as unityreq
           FROM administrativerequests 
           )
           UNION
           (
           SELECT cycleid, orgid, AmountRequested, AmountFunded, 0 as unityreq
           FROM capitalrequests
           )
           UNION
           (
           SELECT cycleid, orgid, AmountRequested, AmountFunded, unityreq
           FROM eventrequests
           )
        ) ilv
      GROUP BY cycleid, orgid, unityreq
    ) ilv,
    fundingcycles fc
    WHERE fc.cycleid=ilv.cycleid
    GROUP BY orgid
```

Comment: Don't think your answer includes `PerOff`, though. I'm guessing another field in `ilv` and another layer of nested `IF()` based on it.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of joining FundingCycles once on the outer select.

Comment: I went back and repurposed this query to use PerOff, but I'm still having the same problem as with Mike's. If there's a request in the same cycle by the same organization with the same amount, it disregards one of the requests in the sum. Are there workarounds for this issue?

Comment: @David Savage: From my understanding of the model, the scenario you describe will not occur with this query. I suggest you re-examine your data / work with a small data set to identify problem. It may be a result of the changes to allow for the peroff value (which I overlooked in my answer above)